# Digits of a HugeInteger Object Stored in a String Object

Tags: c++, string

I am working on a huge integer problem where I have to create a HugeInteger class where the digits are to be stored in a string object instead of an array of unsigned shorts of a fixed (static) size. I am stuck on how to implement this. When I run the program, I input values for my HugeInteger objects but then nothing gets displayed afterwards. Would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my source code of what I have so far.

HugeInteger.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class HugeInteger
{
    // need to offer friendship to these 2 functions
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & src, HugeInteger & value);
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & dest, const HugeInteger & value);

public:
    //ctor that converts a "long long" into a HugeInteger
    HugeInteger(long long value = 0LL); //0LL is constant literal value 0
    //   of type long long
    //ctor that converts a string into a HugeInteger
    HugeInteger( char *str);
    //Convert a string into a HugeInteger
    void input( char *str);

private:
    bool negative;  // will be true if number is negative
    std::string hugeInt; // each digit is stored in a string object
};

//overloads the << and >> operators for the HugeInteger class
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & src, HugeInteger & value);
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & dest, const HugeInteger & value);
```

HugeInteger.cpp

```
#include "HugeInteger.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ctor converts a long long into a HugeInteger
HugeInteger::HugeInteger(long long value)
{
    // set all MaxDigit digits to zero to start
    this->negative = false;
    if (value < 0LL){ // 0LL is constant literal 0 of type long long
        this->negative = true;
        value = -value; // make the value positive                  
    }

    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (; i < hugeInt.size(); i++)
    {
        this->hugeInt[i] = '0';
    }
    this->hugeInt[i] = '\0';

    // convert individual digits of input value into a HugeInteger
    for (unsigned int j = hugeInt.size() - 1; j >= 0 && value != 0LL; j--)
    {
        short result = value % 10;
        char c = (char)result;
        this->hugeInt[j] = c;
        value /= 10;
    }

    // test to make sure that HugeInteger was able to contain value

    if (value != 0LL){
        *this = 0LL; // set to -0, to signal overflow
        this->negative = true; //   Possibly should increase value assigned
    }                          //   to MaxDigit to fix this problem.
}

// converts string into a HugeInteger object
HugeInteger::HugeInteger(char *str)
{
    this->input(str); //See HugeInteger::input() method below
}

void HugeInteger::input( char *str)
{
    // assume positive for now
    this->negative = false;

    // init. to all zeros first
    unsigned int i = 0;

    cin.getline(str, sizeof str);
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();

    while (i < strlen(str) - 1)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            this->hugeInt[i] = str[i];
            i++;
        }
    }

istream & operator>>(istream & input, HugeInteger & value)
{
    char inputString[1002];
    input >> inputString;
    value.input(inputString);
    return input;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & output, const HugeInteger & value)
{
    // find first non-zero digit
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < value.hugeInt.size()){
        if (value.hugeInt[i] != '0'){
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // if all zeros, just output a single 0
    if (i == 40)
    {
        cout << '0';
        return output;
    }

    // check if we need to ouput a negative sign
    if (value.negative){
        cout << '-';
    }

    // output remaining digits
    for (; i < value.hugeInt.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << value.hugeInt[i];
    }

    return output;
}
```

MainProg.cpp

```
#include "HugeInteger.h" // include definiton of class HugeInteger

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        HugeInteger A, B, C, D;

        // input value for A & B
        cout << "****** Test << & >> operators ******\n\n";
        cout << "Input values for A and B: ";
        cin >> A >> B;
        cout << "\nA = " << A << "\nB = " << B;
    system("pause");

        return 0;
    } // end main
```

Comment: How about, like, debugging?

Comment: Just curious, why did you decide on `std::string` instead of, say, a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: `cin.getline(str, sizeof str);`  What do you think this will do?

Comment: My assignment requires that I use the std::string

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code, however the most glaring are your input functions.

First, why does `HugeInteger::input` need to know how the input was retrieved?  There is no need for `cin` or any I/O -- it's job is to solely take a `char *` pointer, and loop through it creating the `hugeInt` string.

Therefore, the lines below should be removed:

```
cin.getline(str, sizeof str);
cin.sync();
cin.clear();
```

The next issue is the actual loop.  There are several things wrong with it.

First, you should be incrementing `i`, regardless if the character is a digit or not.  Otherwise, you will end up in an infinite loop if the character is not a digit.

Second, when you are building the `hugeInt` string, you should be concatentating the character onto the string.  Your current code leads to undefined behavior since you are accessing `hugeInt[i]`, and `hugeInt` is an empty string, so there is no `i` entry.

So the changes there would be this:

```
while (i < strlen(str) - 1)
{
    if (isdigit(str[i]))
        this->hugeInt += str[i];
    i++;
}
```

Now, a better implementation would be to have `input` take a `std::string`, not a char*.  Now, the total function would be rewritten thusly:

```
void HugeInteger::input(const std::string& str)
{
    // assume positive for now
    this->negative = false;

    // init. to all zeros first
    unsigned int i = 0;

    this->hugeInt.clear();
    while (i < str.size())
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            this->hugeInt += str[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

The last issue is your `operator >>`.  There is no need to limit yourself to 1002 characters.  Just input into a `std::string`.

```
istream & operator>>(istream & input, HugeInteger & value)
{
    string inputString;
    input >> inputString;
    value.input(inputString);
    return input;
}
```

After these changes, the sample runs correctly: http://ideone.com/F47TEV

Edit:

An alternate way of extracting the digits and appending onto a string using the STL algorithm functions would be as follows:

```
void HugeInteger::input(std::string str)
{
    // assume positive for now
    this->negative = false;
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char ch) 
                { return !isdigit(ch);}), str.end());
    hugeInt = str;
}
```

The `std::remove_if` is stable, so the relative order of the digits will not be changed.  Also note that we pass by value, as this gives the compiler (if it's C++ 11) a good chance to optimize the copy that is passed (as opposed to making your own copy inside the function).

Comment: Thank you so much Paul. You did an awesome job explaining with your example. I understand what I did wrong now. My code works thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Your current code leads to undefined behavior since you are accessing hugeInt[i], and hugeInt is an empty string, so there is no i entry.

Just to add to this, the lines

```
for (; i < hugeInt.size(); i++)
```

and

```
 for (unsigned int j = hugeInt.size() - 1; j >= 0 && value != 0LL; j--)
```

will never initially execute as `hugeInt.size()` will be 0 and the `for` loop condition will never be satisfied